# FFmpeg: can't capture audio from microphone

Tags: windows-7, audio, ffmpeg, streaming, audio-streaming

I use FFmpeg under Windows 7 to stream live video. There are no problems with the camera, but for some reason I can't capture sound from the microphone (I've tested it, it works fine).

I use the `-list_devices true` command and my microphone is named `Microphone (Realtek High Defini`. But when I set the "audio" parameter to `audio="Microphone (Realtek High Defini"`, an error occurs:

```
[NULL @ 036e2240] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'audio=Microphone
(Realtek High Defini'
audio=Microphone (Realtek High Defini: Invalid argument
```

Here are full commands I use:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

and

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="FaceCam 1320" audio="Microphone (Realtek High Defini" -vcodec h264 -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://localhost/streamApp/cam1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your input parameter is not right, FFmpeg parses your audio as the output file. Try adding a `:`-sign between your video and audio input.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="FaceCam 1320":audio="Microphone (Realtek High Defini" -vcodec h264 -acodec libmp3lame -ac 2 -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://localhost/streamApp/cam1
```

Take a look at the [DirectShow FFmpeg wiki](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/DirectShow) for more information about the right parameter settings.